# How can I migrate GitLab CI/CD pipelines to GitHub Actions with pipelines history?

Tags: github, gitlab, github-actions, gitlab-ci, devops

We have requirement, to migrate GitLab CI/CD pipelines to GitHub Actions with pipelines history.

I tried using GitHub action Importer, but it not capturing the history. I followed below document for GitHub action Importer.
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/migrating-to-github-actions/automated-migrations/migrating-from-gitlab-with-github-actions-importer

So, is there any solution/process to capture pipeline history from GitLab CI/CD to GitHub Actions?

Thanks in Advance.